# Draggable seekbar for HTML5 Audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I am trying to create a seekbar that has a button that shows which part of the track is playing. I want to make it draggable, so users can click on it and move it forward or backward to access another parts of the audio object.

Here is my coed: [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/o4skkxek/2/)

```js
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "https://rjmediamusic.com/media/mp3/mp3-256/Masih-Arash-AP-Bia-Bazam.mp3";


$(audio).on("timeupdate", function() {
  $(".due").text(this.currentTime);
  $(".cirl").css("margin-left", audio.currentTime * (100 / audio.duration) + "%"); // UPDATEs SEEKBAR
});

$(".play").on("click tap", function() {
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
  } else {
    audio.pause();
  }
})


$(".seekbar").on('click tap', function(e) {
  x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left,
    width = $(this).width(),
    duration = audio.duration;
  audio.currentTime = (x / width) * duration;
});
```

```css
.seekbar {
  width: 300px;
  height: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  margin-top: 23px;
}

.seekbar > .cirl {
  width: 1px;
  height: 11px;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  cursor:e-resize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="seekbar">
  <div class="cirl"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="due">0</div>
<br>
<button class="play">Play / Pause</button>
```

Any idea how drag the `.cirl` around to change the `audio.currentTime` position?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible you can make it dragable and attach an event on `drag` event but problem is you need to find some way to only allow horizontal dragging and prevent vertical dragging.I would suggest better to go with `<input type='range'>` it's much easier